# General position of points - different definitions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-topology

For years I've been using the following definition of the **general position** of a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^d:$

"The set of points in $\mathbb R^d$  is in general position iff every $(d+1)$ points **are not** in any possible hyperplane, i.e. no hyperplane contains more than $d$ points."

However, recently I have been reading **Computational topology** by Edelsbrunner and Harer, and their definition is the following:

"We say that the finite set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is in general position if no $d+2$ of the points lie on a common $(d-1)$-sphere."

These definitions are clearly different. To see it, take $d=2$ and consider the set of $4$ points forming a square. They satisfy the first definition, but not the second. Also, take $3$ colinear points. They satisfy the the second definition, but not the first.

So my question is: which definition is more common? Are they somehow related? Is it possible that one of these definitions is known under a different name?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position?

Comment: @LeeMosher , yes, I did take a look at it. They use the first definition, but I found no mention of the second definition.

Comment: It's not a very well written article, however the germ of the answer to your question is there. As it says, under the heading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position#More_generally, "This definition can be generalized further: one may speak of points in general position with respect to a fixed class of algebraic relations... this kind of condition is frequently encountered, in that points should impose independent conditions on curves passing through them."

Comment: @LeeMosher  Oh, I see now. So the meaning of "general position" can depend on the context. Thank you for your answer. If you post what you have written above as an answer to my question, I will upvote it and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"General position" is a very broad term used in many different geometric and topological settings. Both the "planar" definition you're used to and the "spherical" definition you encountered more recently are special cases. Although it's probably too much to try to explain the very broadest generalizations of the term "general position", [this (not very well written) wikipedia page on general position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position) explains a general context into which both of your cases fit, under the heading ["More generally"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position#More_generally).

Comment: Once again, thank you for your time and this wonderful answer.